# PHP : inserting row id to another table

Tags: php, mysql, database

how can I get the row id of tbl_questions and send it to tbl_link_qa
and then tbl_answers get to send it's row number to tbl_link_qa (same with tbl_questions) but this time it must correspond to the first row number from tbl_questions that was inserted first at tbl_link_qa

i need to link the row number of a question from tbl_questions and the row number of an answer from tbl_answers.

need help really bad

rec_id---qRec_id---aRec_id

96------------0-----------0

95------------0-----------0

I need to make it like this >>

rec_id---qRec_id----aRec_id

96----------123----------456

95----------124----------

123 and 124 is the row number from tbl_questions inserted into tbl_link_qa and 456 is from tbl_answers

Comment: Some database fields/tables/queries and code you have tried would help

Comment: no it's not homework, more like my thesis T_T

Comment: One period, no capitalization. Effort in, effort out.

Comment: You have written your question like an IM to a teenager: no capitalization, huge run-on sentences, no formatting. Andrew would like you to put more effort into asking your question if you want others to put effort into providing you with free work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mysql_insert_id` to get the auto_increment ID of the last row you inserted.

Ex:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_questions VALUES (something)");
$question_id = mysql_insert_id();

mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_answer VALUES (something)");
$answer_id = mysql_insert_id();

mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_link_qa (qRec_id, aRec_id) VALUES ($question_id, $answer_id)");
```

Comment: it's not exactly the last row inserted but more like the first row inserted.

Comment: "Last" means "most recent", as in "this is the identifier generated for the INSERT query you most recently ran on this connection". I have saved the ID of the row inserted into each table, what more are you asking for?

Comment: rec_id qRec_id aRec_id
96 0 0
95 0 0        this is what my tbl_link_qa looks like now, qRec_id comes from tbl_questions wherein it's the row number of the question submitted and aRec_id is the row number of the answer from tbl_answers.

Comment: My code gives you the ID of the row from tbl_questions and the ID of the row from tbl_answers... Then it puts them into your link table... Is there a reason you shared this schema with me? Was "question_id" instead of "qRec_id" confusing?

Comment: I guess so, I'm really pretty new in php. I'm not used to coding, I mostly and only do the designs since I do graphics so this is really  a big challenge for me

Comment: this is the code that I'm using now, I took away codes that were intended for tbl_link_qa since I'm still hacking my brain for it  $std_question = $_REQUEST['question']; 
 $idnumber = $_REQUEST['std_id'];
 
 $sql = "Insert into tbl_questions(question,id_std) values('$std_question','$idnumber')";
 $sql2="SELECT * FROM tbl_student WHERE std_id='$idnumber'";
 $q_sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_questions WHERE question = '$std_question'";

Comment: None of that code actually runs any queries against a database, you just assign some strings to some variables... I think you might need more help than you can get in a StackOverflow question. You need a good PHP&MySQL book, a mentor, and a discussion forum.

Comment: Yeah I know. :) Sadly my university didn't teach us all that much about mysql and php. Just a few basics nothing serious. I tried the code you gave me and it worked! Thanks! Now I just have to update the fields so that it would correspond with each other. arec_id inserts itself to a new row. I need to insert it to the same row as it's question

Comment: If you know the question ID and answer ID at the same time, you make one `INSERT` that creates the row having both IDs. If you already have the row with just one ID populated, you use an `UPDATE` query to change the other value.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that now. I'll come back later if I ended screwing up again.